# Prawn PDF causing memory bloat in heroku rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, pdf, heroku, memory

My Heroku Rails app has memory bloating whenever I generate a PrawnPDF. I use the following code for each generation.
Using:
Ruby 2.5.3
Prawn 2.2.2
Prawn-table 0.2.2

```
pdf = InvoicePdf.new(hash)
send_data pdf.render, filename: "receipt_#{order_id}.pdf"
```

And in my mailer, as an attachment:

```
pdf = InvoicePdf.new(hash)
t = Tempfile.create do |f|
  pdf.render_file f
  f.flush
  File.read(f)
end
attachments["receipt.pdf"] = t if t
```

The above code originates here: [Attach Prawn pdf to email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36491009/attach-prawn-pdf-to-email)

Both of these methods cause a memory bloat. The only solution I've seen is to use AWS/cloudinary to store the pdf. I will only use the pdf twice (and neither is time pressured) so this seems a waste. Any ideas?

I have no mem issues at boot.

Thanks, 
Guy

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12068680/how-to-solve-the-memory-leak-with-send-file-or-send-data-on-heroku

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case anyone is looking at this in the future - Ruby GC looked to be messing up. Simply dereferencing the pdf (`pdf = nil`) ensured it was garbage collected.